# Recharts: How to span bars on XAxis when using a number axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, recharts

I am using `recharts` to create a bar chart. The graph can be re-rendered with different time filters. The server response includes only points with data. I get the timestamp for the start of the period + the interval. I also get the start and end of the time range for the chart, so I can use a `type="number"` with a `domain`.

Here is what I came up with

[image]

```js
<ResponsiveContainer>
    <ReBarChart height={300} data={chart.data} barCategoryGap={0} margin={{ bottom: 10 }}>
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <Tooltip labelFormatter={label => <TooltipLabel label={label} interval={chart.dates.interval} />} />
      {chart.keys.map(key => (
        <Bar {...key} stackId="a" barSize={32} />
      ))}
      <YAxis />
      <XAxis dataKey="time" tick={<XAxisLabel />} type="number" domain={[chart.dates.from, chart.dates.to]} />
    </ReBarChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
```

The issue is that I'm getting very narrow `bars` with a gap in between. Is there a way for me to take the whole width ? Instead of declaring 1 value for XAxis, declare a `from` and `to` ?

(playing with `barSize` didn't yield any result as it will get capped by the number axis)